# How to run people package succesfully?

Tags: ros, laser, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all!  I am learning and trying to run [people package](http://wiki.ros.org/people) on a real kobuki( i.e. turtlebot2) with a hokuyo laser under hydro of ROS. Because there is no tutorial on how to run and use it . I have to try to find out how to write a launch file to run it on a real kobuki. However, I encounter a problem which is same with [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/78026/problem-with-leg_detector-and-people_tracking_filter/).

I also can't launch the filter.launch from people_tracking_filter. The key parts for running people package is listed as follows

```
 ...............
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>

  <arg name="limit" default="0.2" />
  <param name="/leg_detector/leg_reliability_limit" value="$(arg limit)" type="double"/>
  <include file="$(find map_laser)/lfilter.launch"/>
  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector" args="scan:=scan_filtered $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml"/>
  <include file="$(find people_tracking_filter)/launch/filter.launch"/>
  <node name="velocity_tracker" pkg="people_velocity_tracker" type="tracker.py" respawn="true" />
...............
```

Please note that the sub-package map_laser doesn't exist in the hydro branch of [People package](http://wiki.ros.org/people), I downloaded it from an unofficial site of it to use lfilter.launch as some launch files in People Package show.

I also check the cpp code of people_tracking_filter by Qtcreator. Some header file (.h) can't be traced.
Does anyone can give me guidance on how to run it succesfully? Thank you！

@David Lu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193353/how-to-run-people-package-succesfully?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can download the map_laser package as a binary. The source code is also here: https://github.com/DLu/laser_filtering/

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-25**:
Thank you, David. But the problem is not about Map_laser, it is about the people-tracking-filter. Tbe filter.launch in it can’t be run succesfuly.  The same error with [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/78026/problem-with-leg_detector-and-people_tracking_filter/)  happened.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-25**:
That is , the message PositionMeasurementArray is not compatible. The error is " Client [/people_tracker] wants topic /people_tracker_measurements to have datatype/md5sum [people_msgs/PositionMeasurement/54fa938b4ec28728e01575b79eb0ec7c], but our version has [people_msgs/PositionMeasurementArray/59c

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-09-26**:
That is a known bug that I have not had time to fix. However, it should not impede you from running the leg detector, I believe. https://github.com/wg-perception/people/issues/10

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-28**:
Thank you! I will try to fix this bug. when I have time, I will read its code and find a way to fix it by extending it to track many people.